# Join Two Tables with mixed columns oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to join two tables.

## Table 1

```
Columns  A,  B,  C
Row 1   10, 20, 30
Row 2   40, 50, 60
```

## Table 2

```
Columns  A,  B,  D
Row 1   70, 80, 90
Row 2    5,  6,  7
```

## After Join

```
Output should be
Columns  A,  B,    C,    D
Row 1   10, 20,   30, null
Row 2   40, 50,   60, null
Row 3   70, 80, null,   90
Row 4    5,  6, null,    7
```

Comment: Question is very unclear. Please add more information

Comment: I think so you need this.. `select table1.a,table1.b.table1.c,table2.d from table1 inner join table2 on table1.a=table2.a and table1.b = table2.b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `UNION ALL`

```
select a, b, c, null d from table1
union all
select a, b, null, d from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

try it. This question has a lot of answers but i think this is most suitable for this case:

```
    select a, b, c, null as d
    from table1 
    union all
    select a, b, null as c, d
    from table2;
```